# Wrong distance calculation between two Points in django

Tags: python, django, postgis, geos

I have a model that uses PointField to store location:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point


class Post(models.Model)
    location = models.PointField()
```

and trying to do the following calculation:

```
initial_location = Post.objects.first().location
last_location = Post.objects.last().location

total_distance = initial_location.distance(last_location)
```

The values for this locations are:

```
print(initial_location)
>>> SRID=4326;POINT (-1.407385628884526 -24.29361291088179)
print(last_location)
>>> SRID=4326;POINT (65.55023895708794 43.8537639564256)
print(total_distance)
>>> 95.53736684717059
```

Ok, at first glance I thought it was working, but this value is totally wrong.
Using [this site](https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/dms-decimal) to convert decimal coordinates to degrees coords and [this site](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml) to calculate the distance based on this coords, I get a result almost 100 times higher than Django is printing.

I'm not sure what is wrong since all of these methods and functions are built-in of the Point class.

Comment: The distances are linear, not spherical as is specified in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.distance You use the *haversine* function to determine the spherical distance.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you Willem!